# cant seem to be able to update the start and end point of my filter

Tags: angular

im trying to filter an array to filter from a start date to and end date. how ever im not being able to update the start or end date. when i try to update it doesnt change.

```
export class AppComponent {
  snapshots = [
    { date: '01-02-2017', roomOccupancyCount: 2869, userCount: 1783, location: 'All' },
    { date: '01-05-2017', roomOccupancyCount: 2769, userCount: 1655, location: 'All' },
    { date: '03-02-2017', roomOccupancyCount: 2025, userCount: 1911, location: 'All' },
    { date: '01-02-2017', roomOccupancyCount: 1278, userCount: 1167, location: 'All' },
    { date: '02-02-2017', roomOccupancyCount: 2028, userCount: 1940, location: 'All' },
    { date: '01-10-2017', roomOccupancyCount: 2113, userCount: 2001, location: 'All' },
    { date: '03-02-2017', roomOccupancyCount: 2654, userCount: 1841, location: 'All' },
    { date: '01-02-2017', roomOccupancyCount: 1264, userCount: 1140, location: 'All' },
    { date: '01-02-2017', roomOccupancyCount: 2918, userCount: 2557, location: 'All' },
    { date: '01-20-2017', roomOccupancyCount: 2160, userCount: 2112, location: 'All' }
  ];
  start = '01-02-2017';
  end = '03-03-2017';


   ngOnInit() { 
    this.snapshots = this.snapshots.filter(m => {
      if ( m.date > this.start && m.date < this.end)
      return m
    })
   }

update(updateForm:NgForm):void {
  console.log(updateForm.value);
}
```

Comment: Comapring Dates like a string won't give you correct results, compare then as dates. Also please explain your date format, is it `mm-dd-yyyy` or `dd-mm-yyyy`?

Comment: the format is mm--dd-yyyy

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of solving your problem.

1. Converting your date strings as date objects and comparing their times

If your format is "mm-dd-yyyy", then your dates can easily be converted into Date Objects, using `new Date(dateString)`.

```
ngOnInit() {
    let comparableStartDate = new Date(this.start)
    let comparableEndDate = new Date(this.end)
    this.snapshots = this.snapshots.filter(m => {
        let mDate = (new Date(m)).getTime()
        if ( mDate > (new Date(this.start)).getTime() && mDate < (new Date(this.end)).getTime()) {
            return true
        }
    })
}
```

2. Converting the dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` format and comparing them as strings.

This is the code for comparing them as strings:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let comparableStartDate = this.start.replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$3-$1-$2")
    let comparableEndDate = this.end.replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$3-$1-$2")
    this.snapshots = this.snapshots.filter(m => {
        let mDate = m.replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$3-$1-$2")
        if ( mDate > comparableStartDate && mDate < comparableEndDate) {
            return true
        }
    })
}
```